# Equivalent definitions of relative open sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

From pg. 148 of "An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series" by Howard J. Wilcox and David L. Myers:

> A set $A$ of real numbers is open (in $\mathcal{R}$) if for each $x \in A$, there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \subset A$.
>
> Sometimes it is desirable to focus attention on a subset $X$ of $\mathcal{R}$ and to speak of subsets $A \subset X$ as being open or closed relative to $X$. A set $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ (or "in the relative topology of $X$") if there is a set $U$, open in $\mathcal{R}$, such that $A = U \cap X$. The reader can verify that a set $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ if and only if for every $x \in A$ there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \cap X \subset A$.

I am attempting to verify the last statement. That is:

Definition 1: A set $A$ of real numbers is open (in $\mathcal{R}$) if for each $x \in A$, there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \subset A$.

Definition 2: Let $X \subset \mathcal{R}$. A set $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ if there is a set $U$, open in $\mathcal{R}$, such that $A = U \cap X$.

Theorem: Let $X \subset \mathcal{R}$. A set $A \subset X$ is open in $X$ if and only if for every $x \in A$ there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \cap X \subset A$.

Proof:

(=>) Let $X \subset \mathcal{R}$. Let $A \subset X$ be open in $X$. Then from Definition 2 there is a set $U$, open in $\mathcal{R}$, such that $A = U \cap X$. Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in U$. Since $U$ is open in $\mathcal{R}$, then by Definition 1 there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \subset U$. Since $(a, b) \subset U$ and $A = U \cap X$, then $(a, b) \cap X \subset A$.

(<=) Let $X \subset \mathcal{R}$. Let $A \subset X$. Suppose for every $x \in A$ there is an open interval $(a, b)$ such that $x \in (a, b)$ and $(a, b) \cap X \subset A$.

That is for every $x \in A$ there is an open interval $I_{x}$ such that $x \in I_{x}$ and $I_{x} \cap X \subset A$. Let $U = \cup_{x \in A} I_{x}$.

Let $x \in U$. Then there exists an $x'$ such that $x \in I_{x'}$ and $I_{x'} \subset U$. Then $U$ is open in $\mathcal{R}$.

Let $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$ then there is an open interval $I_{x}$ such that $x \in I_{x}$ and $I_{x} \subset U$. Then $x \in U$. Since $A \subset X$ then $x \in X$. Then $x \in U \cap X$.

Let $x \in U \cap X$. Since $x \in U$ then there exists an $x'$ such that $x \in I_{x'}$ and $I_{x'} \cap X \subset A$. Since $x \in X$ then $x \in I_{x'} \cap X$. Then $x \in A$.

Then $A = U \cap X$.

I am not certain if I have done this correctly, especially the second part (<=). Is this correct? Can it be improved?

Comment: Looks good to me. :)